# Replace ascii character with unicode

Tags: vba, unicode, ascii, ms-word

This is my code in word vba macro

```
Public sub as2uni()
    Dim rdcm As Range 
    Set rdcm = ActiveDocument.Range 
    With rdcm.Find    
     .MatchCase = True     
      rdcm.Select     
     .Text = "0079"
     .Replacement.Text = "\U0BB2"
     .Execute , , , , , , , , , , wdRepl
   End with
End sub
```

I just want to **replace the ASC to Unicode** in **ALL** my document, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the purpose of your macro... I understand that you want to replace all capital "O" with the Latha-script formatted character ல

In that case, you need to change how you specify the Replace term. The *^Unnn* format for Unicode is only valid for the "Find what" box. In order to figure this out, I copied and pasted the ல into the Replace box in Word's interface then executed the Find/Replace. Looking at the recorded code revealed you need to use the function ChrW to specify the Unicode representation in a macro.

In addition, you need to change how you specify searching ANSI 79, as below.

```
Public Sub as2uni() 'Latha
    Dim rdcm As Range
    Set rdcm = ActiveDocument.Range
    With rdcm.Find
        .ClearFormatting
     .MatchCase = True
     ' rdcm.Select
     .Text = "^79"
     .Replacement.Text = ChrW(2994)
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub
```